# Can't type in editText on Mac emulator

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, android-edittext

I am a new Mac OS user and I transfered my Android project to Mac after installing Eclipse and all the necessary requirments. My application is running normally, but I can't seem to type in the emulator.

I am running an Android 4.1 emulator using Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a problem with the new release of the Android Tools. You will need to edit the AVD to add an option as follows:

From Eclipse, Go to AVD Mananger.

- Select the particular AVD and click on Edit
- Go to the Hardware section, click on New.
- Select the Property Name : Keyboard Support
- By default, it is added with a value of 'no'. Just click on the value column and change it to 'yes'.
- Click on Edit AVD again.

This will add a property `hw.keyboard=yes` in `config.ini` file for the AVD. And it should work fine from there.

Comment: Yes! Why is this not the default??

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by @Romin looked promising, but unfortunately did not work for me in SDK 4.0.3. No how many times I changed it to "yes" it would still revert back to "no" after clicking "Edit AVD" (why no "save" button?)

My solution was to simply edit the `.ini` file directly:

1. edit `$HOME/.android/avd/your-device.avd/config.ini`.
2. change `hw.keyboard=yes`

Answer (score 0):

On **Genymotion**, edit the AVD and set "Use Virtual Keyboard for Text Input".